# Monte Carlo Simulation code/ library in Python

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, montecarlo, forecast

I am trying to learn how to apply Monte Carlo simulation in Python for predicting/estimating time series data such as sales/deposits volumes, interest rates etc. I can understand the basic idea behind the method.

So I am wondering if there is anywhere a practical example of step by step explanation on how to develop the Monte Carlo model (i.e. choose distribution, apply for loop for selected parameters etc.) As you can understand I am new to the 'sport'.

Any help or suggestion/assistance is much appreciated.

Thanks

I looked at Python libraries, such us Statsmodels, but I couldn't find any relevant simulation model. I looked also at examples such as the one below:

[Monte Carlo Simulation in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049965/monte-carlo-simulation-in-python)

but I am searching for something that elaborates more on the application process.

Comment: You want to do it by hand? Better use something like PyMC3, https://www.ritchievink.com/blog/2018/10/09/build-facebooks-prophet-in-pymc3-bayesian-time-series-analyis-with-generalized-additive-models/

Comment: No I dont want to do it by hand. Since I am not into "heavy" statistics I would prefer using some ready made function found in a library or study an example of an existing code to learn by practise. I would chech PyMC3. Thanks

Comment: Good. Alongside PyMC there are Stan/PyStan, Edward, Pyro

Comment: If you are looking for "real" distributions to sample for simulations, try my new library: MicceriRD - https://pypi.org/project/MicceriRD/